# How can I improve LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, select, where-clause

So this question is about `.Select()` statements on a static collection (ie not the result of a `Select()`, `Where()` or other LINQ operation, for example a `List` of `array`).

I was under the impression that when using `.Select()` or other non-filtering, non-sorting methods, a `.ElementAt()` would take the element from the original collection and run it through the `.Select`. I saw this as the best way as the `.ElementAt()` only returns one element and LINQ does not cache anything, so the other generated items get thrown away.

To provide an example:

```
var original = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);

var listWithADifficultSelect = original.Select(aMethod);

var onlyOneItem = listWithADifficultSelect.ElementAt(898);

object aMethod(int number) {
    // Gets the item from some kind of database, difficult operation
    // Takes at least a few milliseconds
    return new object();
}
```

To see this in the bigger picture, if I have a list of 20K items and I only need the n<sup>th</sup> item, but I perform a pretty heavy `.Select()`, I would expect the `.Select()` to only project that one item from the list.

So I have a two-fold question here:

1. Why is this built this way?
2. Is there a way to build an improved `.Select()` that does what I want it to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Can you provide an example of what you mean? To me it sounds like you misunderstood `Select`. If you only need the n-th item, just take it.

Comment: if its a normal collection, i can index it like an array like this one, List[nth-item]. No need to use a select

Comment: You properbly want to use FirstOrDefault. There is nothing wrong with select, its a great quick function if you wanna convert an entire collection into something else. But ofc you can always make your own LINQ extensions if you need aomething they do not have.

Comment: `Select` is not for accessing elements in the sequence, it's for _projecting_ this elements into something different.

Comment: I have edited my question with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you don't want LINQ to call `aMethod` for the first 897 elements if you only need the 898th.

So why don't you call it like that:

```
var onlyOneItem = aMethod(original.ElementAt(898));
```

If you want to get several specific elements and just don't want LINQ to re-evaluate `aMethod` all the time, then turn your result into a `List` or array:

```
var listWithADifficultSelect = original.Select(aMethod).ToList(); // or ToArray();
```

So the `Select` with all its `aMethod` calls is only executed once and you can access all your elements without re-calling `aMethod`.

---

If you want to write your own LINQ methods that do more what you want than LINQ already does, you can easily implement your own extensions:

```
public static class MyLinq
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> MySelect<TSource,TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TResult> selector)
    {
        // implement yourself
    }
    public static TSource MyElementAt<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, int index)
    {
        // implement yourself
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. I guess I will have to go for the first option as the second one not only calls `aMethod` for the first 897 items, but also for the remaining items (worse than only doing `.Select` once, but not as bad as doing `.Select` twice)

Comment: I now notice why this does not work like I think it should. Only `IEnumerables` are passed around, and every action does a simple operation using a `foreach` and maybe `yield`. This has the inherent issue that you cannot pass through the information like "I don't need these n items".

Answer (score 3):

A universal solution that would even translate well to SQL (if that's an issue) would be to use `Skip` and `Take`. You can skip the first `n-1` items and then take `1` from your original `IEnumerable` (or `IQueryable`).

```
var original = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);
var onlyOneItem = original.Skip(898 - 1).Take(1).Select(aMethod);
```

`Skip` and `Take` are Linq's equivalent of SQL's `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`.

*In a simplified case like your example, you won't see any improvements to performance, but if you have an expensive query in your actual application, this way you can avoid fetching any unnecessary elements*